# Как сделать чтобы закрывалось дочернее окно после закрытия главного?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Друзья, Прошу Вашей помощи. Я создаю шаблон через `QtDesigner` (в данном примере форма с единственной кнопкой), после чего создаю класс дочернего окна.
Нужно чтобы оно закрывалось автоматически, после закрытия основного окна - window:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("untitled.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()


def open_window1():
    window1.show()


form.pushButton.clicked.connect(open_window1)


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Дочернее окно")
        # self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)  # +++ Qt.Window


window1 = Window1()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Не понял как на данной платформе вкладывать файлы, поэтому не смог приложить шаблон, да и не думаю что это так важно. В данном примере шаблон это форма с единственной кнопкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите главное окно как родительское для дочернего и при закрытии главного, дочернее закроется автоматически.

Если наследование от `QWidget`:

```
...
class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog)

window1 = Window1(window)
...
```

Если наследование от `QDialog` (рекомендую):

```
...
class Window1(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

window1 = Window1(window)
...
```

Еще вариант - связать сигнал закрытия одного окна со слотом закрытия другого.

Comment: Alexander Chernin, исправил код как вы сказали. Теперь по кнопке окно window1 перестало вообще открываться.
Полный код в выложу сообщении ниже

Comment: @StasP да, точно. Надо либо указать у QWidget, что он окно, либо наследоваться от QDialog (рекомендую). Исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вариантов много. Один из вариантов выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("untitled.ui")    


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Дочернее окно")
        

class MainWindow(Window, Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)        
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_window1)
        
        self.window1 = Window1()

    def open_window1(self):
        self.window1.show()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):              # +++
        self.window1.close()                  # +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```